# How to reset timer resolution to default in Windows 10 2004?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-10

I successfully changed the timing resolution to 0.5ms using the following:

```
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI NtSetTimerResolution(ULONG DesiredResolution, BOOLEAN SetResolution, PULONG CurrentResolution);
extern "C" NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI NtQueryTimerResolution(OUT PULONG MinimumResolution, OUT PULONG MaximumResolution, OUT PULONG CurrentResolution);

ULONG minimum_resolution;
ULONG maximum_resolution;
ULONG current_resolution;
NtQueryTimerResolution(&minimum_resolution, &maximum_resolution, &current_resolution);
NtSetTimerResolution(maximum_resolution, TRUE, &current_resolution);
```

However, I am unable to restore it to its original value of 156250.

My attempt:

```
NtQueryTimerResolution(&minimum_resolution, &maximum_resolution, &current_resolution);

std::cout << "minimum = " << minimum_resolution << "\nmaximum = " << maximum_resolution << "\ncurrent = " << current_resolution << "\n";

auto result = NtSetTimerResolution(minimum_resolution, FALSE, &current_resolution);

std::cout << "after setting using FALSE, current = " << current_resolution << "\n";

NtQueryTimerResolution(&minimum_resolution, &maximum_resolution, &current_resolution);

std::cout << "now, minimum = " << minimum_resolution << "\nmaximum = " << maximum_resolution << "\ncurrent = " << default_resolution << "\n";

result = NtSetTimerResolution(minimum_resolution, TRUE, &current_resolution);

std::cout << "after setting using TRUE, current = " << current_resolution << "\n";
```

yields the following output:

```
minimum = 156250
maximum = 5000
current = 4999
after setting using FALSE, current = 9999
now, minimum = 156250
maximum = 5000
current = 9999
after setting using TRUE, current = 9999
```

Strangely, the 9999 value does not persist; successive invocations yield the same output (without setting the timer using the first block of code); even rebooting does not restore anything.  I have ensured Visual Studio and browsers are closed.  Using timeBeginPeriod and timeEndPeriod also did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Do call the `NtQueryTimerResolution` again after the `NtSetTimerResolution` and then print the log.

Additionally it is good to check the function's result.